# I need to convert full name in to a name with initials in laravel Ex: Simmon Alexander Hales to S.A. Hales

Tags: laravel

$names=Player::pluck('fullname');
$initials=[];

```
    foreach($names as $name) {
        $nameParts = explode(' ', trim($name));
        $firstName = array_shift($nameParts);
        $lastName = array_pop($nameParts);
        $initials[$name] = (
            mb_substr($firstName,0,1) .
            mb_substr($lastName,0,1)
        );
    }
```

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/, but anyway: you need to come up with an algorithm that works. If you have described that, implementing it is trivial. For all "name parts" split by space, you want the first letter of each before the last (if any), followed by a dot, followed by the last part.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$names = Player::pluck('fullname');
$initials = [];

foreach ($names as $name) {
    $initials[$name] = trim(collect(explode(' ', $name))->map(function ($segment) {
        return mb_substr($segment, 0, 1);
    })->join('.'));
}

print_r($initials);
```

**Update:**

```php
$names = Player::pluck('fullname');
$initials = [];

foreach ($names as $name) {
    $initials[$name] = trim(collect(explode(' ', $name))->reverse()->values()->map(function ($item, $key) {
        if ($key == 0) {
            return ' ' . $item;
        } else {
            return mb_substr($item, 0, 1);
        }
    })->reverse()->join('.'));
}

print_r($initials);
```

Comment: need to remain last name

Comment: It's working now. See the update section.